# nfs /etc/fstab doesn't mount on startup: ubuntu / xbmc

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, fstab, kodi

I have an nfs share I'm trying to mount automatically at startup in ubuntu / xbmc

I have the following in `/etc/fstab`

```
nas:/mnt/raid /mnt/raid nfs noauto,rw,async
```

On startup the mount doesn't automatically occur.

If I issue a manual `mount` command it works:

```
$ sudo mount -o noauto,rw,async -t nfs nas:/mnt/raid /mnt/raid
```

How can I get this mount to occur automatically on startup?

Looking for errors in `/var/log/messages` doesn't yield much, but it does say something about **nodiskmount**:

```
Kernel command line: \
    BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-29-generic \
    root=UUID=e575a39a-09d9-4747-befa-466c7aae64d1 \
    ro quiet splash \
    xbmc=autostart,nodiskmount \                       <-- THIS LINE
    loglevel=0 \
    video=vesafb
```

Could this be the problem? Is there any way to disable `nodiskmount`?

I am using the *XBMCFreak LiveCD 10* from [XBMCFreak.nl](http://www.xbmcfreak.nl/en/) which is based on `Ubuntu lucid lynx`

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS - XBMCLive
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing “`noauto`” to “`auto`” in `/etc/fstab`.